# JavaScript Confirm Box returning Code Instead of Function Value

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I created a real simple form and used JS to access the value of the radio button, then make a quick calculation and return a string in a popup box based on a function.  The problem is when the button is clicked, the pop up returns the code for the called function and not the string.

```
     <div id="questionaire">
        <div id="question1">    
            <h2>How familiar are you with Javascript?</h2><br>
            <form id="first_q">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4">Very Experienced.</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3">I've Worked with the Basics.</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">I Only Know Its a Programming Language.</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">Java...Mmm, Coffee sounds GOOD!</input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="question2">
            <h2>How much do you like to code?</h2><br>
            <form id="second_q">
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4">I think about coding during sex!</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3">It's safe to say, I take coding pretty_seriously.</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2">I would consider it my cold-weather hobby.</input><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">Technology is cool.</input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="answer">
        <button id="color-switcher">TELL ME MORE...</button>
    </div>
```

Externally Linked JS

```
var q1_rating = function() {
var first_q_answer = document.getElementsByName("q1");

for(var i = 0; i < first_q_answer.length; i++) {
  if(first_q_answer[i].checked == true) {
    q1_value = first_q_answer[i].value;
  }
}

return parseFloat(q1_value);
};

var q2_rating = function() {
var second_q_answer = document.getElementsByName("q2");

for(var i = 0; i < second_q_answer.length; i++) {
  if(second_q_answer[i].checked == true) {
    q2_value = second_q_answer[i].value;
  }
}

return parseFloat(q2_value);
};

var final_rating = function() {
total_value = (q1_rating + q2_rating);

if (total_value > 6) {
    return "You're a TRUE NERD ready to conquer the world.";
} else if (total_value > 4 && total_value <=6) {
    return "You need some more work, but you're coming along nicely.";
} else if (total_value >2 && total_value <=4) {
    return "You need to step up your nerd game pronto!";
} else {
    return "You're more jock than nerd";
}
};

document.getElementById('color-switcher').addEventListener('click', function(){
    confirm(final_rating);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `final_rating` function

```
 confirm(final_rating());
```

Currently, You are passing the reference of function

Comment: Oh man! Definitely need to call my functions. Thanks for the fresh pair of eyes.